# Writing a LINQ query to traverse many tables

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I wanted to write a LINQ query based on the SQL below.

Basically this strategy seems really confusing - why start from MerchantGroupMerchant and do 2 'from' statements?

**Problem:** Is there a simpler way to write this LINQ query?

```
var listOfCampaignsMerchantIsInvolvedIn =
    (from merchantgroupactivity in uow.MerchantGroupActivities
     from merchantgroupmerchant in uow.MerchantGroupMerchants
     where merchantgroupmerchant.MerchantU.Id == merchantUIDGuid  
     select new
     {
         merchantgroupactivity.ActivityU.CampaignU.Id
     }).Distinct();
```

Here is the table structure:
[image]

and the SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Campaign.ID
    FROM Campaign 
    INNER JOIN Activity
        ON ( Campaign.CampaignUID = Activity.CampaignUID )
    INNER JOIN MerchantGroupActivity
        ON ( Activity.ActivityUID = MerchantGroupActivity.ActivityUID )
    INNER JOIN MerchantGroup
        ON ( MerchantGroup.MerchantGroupUID =  MerchantGroupActivity.MerchantGroupUID )
    INNER JOIN MerchantGroupMerchant
        ON ( MerchantGroupMerchant.MerchantGroupUID = MerchantGroup.MerchantGroupUID )
    INNER JOIN Merchant
        ON ( Merchant.MerchantUID = MerchantGroupMerchant.MerchantUID )
    WHERE Merchant.ID = 'M1'
```

Comment: Create a view and then apply the Linq2Sql.

Comment: Thats certainly an option cheers, but ideally I want to keep everything in the LINQ query for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really, even if you use views to partially or completely reduce query size your execution plan will still look the same in the end (and execute just as fast/slow). If you have to traverse 5 joins then you have to traverse 5 joins, the only cure is "shorting" the model by introducing links between say merchant and activity or merchant and campaign. You can accomplish this by either introducing the M2M table between them (at the cost of manual maintenance), but I would not recommend it unless retrieval is really an issue. If this query is too slow you should check for existence of indexes on all join FK fields.

Comment: I'm not after performance here!  Just readability of the query.  The structure of the DB is set, so can't change it.  Ideally I'd like a simpler LINQ query...

Comment: well, I don't think you can go any simpler here, you are already using a trick with two from statements (via intermediary) that you would otherwise need to specify in join if using one from statement, thereby making the query longer. This LINQ query you have is very readable if you know what multiple from statements stand for (every combination of all objects from all sources)